# Select multiple rows into one variable in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT ft.ThreadTitle AS Title, 
fr.ReplyText + ' ' + ua2.Username + ' ' + ft.ThreadText + ' '  +

-- THIS NEXT LINE IS WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE:

(Select ReplyText from ForumReply Where ThreadID=ft.ThreadID) 

-- THE ABOVE LINE HAVE MULTIPLE ROWS/VALUES THAT I WANT TO JOIN INTO ONE VARIABLE. HOW?
AS [Content], 

ss.Domain, 
ss.SiteID, 
ft.ThreadID AS ObjectId
FROM         dbo.ForumReply AS fr INNER JOIN
                      dbo.ForumThreads AS ft ON fr.ThreadID = ft.ThreadID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.User_Account AS ua1 ON ft.CreateByUserID = ua1.UserID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.User_Account AS ua2 ON fr.ReplyUserID = ua2.UserID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.SysT_Site AS ss ON ua1.SiteID = ss.SiteID
```

This query gives error:
*Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.*

How do I rewrite this query to work so that I get all the values into one variable? The end result need to be a "View" that looks like this:

.ObjectID int

.Content (string with all text that exists in the Forumthread.threadText and forumReply.ReplyText)

.Domain string

.SiteID int

Comment: That is exactly what I don`t want. I want all recordsets and join them together into one value

Comment: You can concatenate values from multiple rows into a string in SQL Server using `XML PATH`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Building upon Martin's comment:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE  (id int, ReplyText varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @t (id, ReplyText) VALUES (1, 'So Long,')
INSERT INTO @t (id, ReplyText) VALUES  (2, 'And Thanks for')
INSERT INTO @t (id, ReplyText) VALUES  (3, 'All the Fish!')

SELECT (SELECT replytext + ' '  FROM @t FOR XML PATH('')) AS CONTENT
```

Comment: Number 3 should be "all the fish" ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can assign to local variable this way.

```
SELECT @TempVariable = (SELECT replytext + ' ' FROM @t FOR XML PATH(''))
```

Comment: @t is DECLARE @t TABLE  (id int, ReplyText varchar(100))

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a string concat aggregate function, which sql server unfortunuatley does not include.

You can create your own though using .Net CLr function see [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1691) and [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/)

Answer (score 1):

I used STUFF:

```
SELECT
MyTable.Number AS Number,
(SELECT stuff(
    (
    select ', ' + x from (SELECT MyOtherTable.Name AS x FROM MyOtherTable WHERE MyOtherTable.ID = MyTable.ID) tb 
    FOR XML PATH('')
    )
, 1, 2, ''))AS AllNames

FROM
MyTable
```

Result:

```
Number:   AllNames:
  1       Andrew, Carl
  2       Bobby, Dave
```